# Zend Server and php includes - not processing correctly

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, unix, include

I've run into some code in config.php in a php codeingniter app running on a Zend server which checks for the existence of a different file, configx.php. If it's there, it includes it, otherwise it executes the code within itself. It looks like this:

```
if (file_exists('/opt/myapp/configx.php')) {
    include '/opt/myapp/configx.php';
} else {
.... normal config code
```

(configx.php doesn't include the check for configx.php)

When I try to run the app (I've tried chrome and firefox) it doesn't recognize that the file needs to be interpreted and instead tries to download it. The file type is:

```
application/x-httpd-php
```

This is handled in zend.conf:

```
AddHandler zend-enabler-script .php 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

But isn't mentioned in httpd.conf.

What's the best way to include this file? Is it a unix/windows problem?

Comment: `include` is a PHP directive and is independent of the Web server software.  It shouldn't cause Apache to try to force download a file unless it has specific code in it to do so.  Does the same thing happen when you comment the include?

Answer (score 0):

There are likely syntax errors. You can check by running:

```
php -l /opt/myapp/configx.php
```